# Extract a base64binary from a WebService in ORACLE and use it as a BLOB

Tags: sql, oracle, web-services, blob

I made this WebService in .NET which response is a byte[] which is a base64binary. I need to receive this in ORACLE (10.2.0).
I already have the response stored in a CLOB variable, I can read the value of the response this way:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(l_clob),
               '//GetBlobResponse/GetBlobResult/text()',
               'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"')
  FROM DUAL;
```

This throws me something like **"JVBERi0xLjMNCiX5+prnDQo1IDAgb2JqDQo8PA0KL..."** and so on, all this on a XMLTYPE CLOB COLUMN.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
DECLARE
VAR BLOB;
BEGIN
SELECT EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(l_clob),
               '//GetBlobResponse/GetBlobResult/text()',
               'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"')
  INTO VAR
  FROM DUAL;
END;
```

I tried to do **"VAR CLOB"** with no luck.

I don't want to insert this on a TABLE, I want to use it with another Procedure that receives a BLOB.

And for the record is a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Well i hitted the answer,after doin this:

```
    DECLARE
    l_xml  XMLTYPE;
    l_clob CLOB;
    x_clob CLOB;
    l_blob BLOB;
    BEGIN

    x_clob := '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetBlobResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetBlobResult>[BASE64BINARY]</GetBlobResult>
        </GetBlobResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

    SELECT EXTRACT(XMLTYPE(x_clob),
               '//GetBlobResponse/GetBlobResult/text()',
               'xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"')
    INTO l_xml
    FROM DUAL;

    l_clob := l_xml.getClobVal();
    l_blob := F_DECODE_BASE64(l_clob);

    END;
```

With the function doin this:

```
FUNCTION F_DECODE_BASE64(p_clob_in in clob) return blob is
    v_blob blob;
    v_result blob;
    v_offset integer;
    v_buffer_size binary_integer := 48;
    v_buffer_varchar varchar2(48);
    v_buffer_raw raw(48);
  BEGIN
    IF p_clob_in is null then
      return null;
    END IF;
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_blob, true);
    v_offset := 1;
    FOR i in 1 .. ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob_in) / v_buffer_size)    LOOP
      dbms_lob.read(p_clob_in, v_buffer_size, v_offset, v_buffer_varchar);
      v_buffer_raw := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(v_buffer_varchar);
      v_buffer_raw := utl_encode.base64_decode(v_buffer_raw);
      dbms_lob.writeappend(v_blob, utl_raw.length(v_buffer_raw), v_buffer_raw);
      v_offset := v_offset + v_buffer_size;
    END LOOP;
    v_result := v_blob;
    dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_blob);
    RETURN v_result;
  END f_decode_base64;
```

This gave me the answer i was lookin for.